# Is there a number field $K$ such that $K^\times / \mathbb{Q}^\times$ is finitely generated?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

I think I have a simple proof that the only fields with finitely generated multiplicative groups are finite. What about if we take $K$ a number field and mod out $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ from its multiplicative group? Can $K^\times / \mathbb{Q}^\times$ be finitely generated?

Comment: You can assume the extension is Galois. Assuming that the degree of the extension is $n>1$. You still need to use the norm map. You also need to show that infinite number of primes appear as a factor in the image of the norm map that its exponent is not divisible by $n$. For this you just need to show infinite number of primes do not split in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: As follows from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/18380/14094), for a field extension $K\subset L$, the group $L^*/K^*$ is finitely generated iff $K=L$ or $L$ is finite (i.e., never except in trivial cases).

Comment: Maybe there are refinements of this result. E.g., one could ask whether this group always has infinite $\mathbf{Q}$-rank (this time, when $K\neq L$ and $L$ is not algebraic over a finite field). This might follow from the given argument but I'm not competent enough to see this clearly.